# Show a value inside a prompt in R

Tags: r, prompt

I have been searching this for some time and haven't been able to find the answer. Hope you can help me:

```
a <- readline(prompt="No. of attributes: ")
lev <- c()
i <- 0
while (i<a) {
  l <- readline(prompt="No. of levels in attribute i: ")
  l <- as.numeric(strsplit(l,",")[[1]])
  lev <- c(lev, l)
  i=i+1
}
```

Inside the loop, in the prompt in l, I want i to change by the real value of i.
Sorry for being such a noob.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "assign the prompt value to 'i'"? Wouldn't this work?
(edited)
Seems like you need three changes --

1. use `paste0` (which concatenates raw text with string variables, with "0" spaces, i.e., no spaces)
2. your need to assign to "l" to correctly so the prompt increments
3. You maybe want i to start at 1, and change the `i<a` to `i<=a` so you are correctly getting each level:

```
a <- readline(prompt="No. of attributes: ")
lev <- c()
i <- 1
while (i<=a) {
  l <- readline(prompt=paste0("No. of levels in attribute ",i,": "))
  l <- as.numeric(strsplit(l,",")[[1]])
  lev <- c(lev, l)
  i=i+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
prompt=paste0("No. of levels in attribute ", i, ":")
```

**Edit:** FYI, there's also a `paste` function that is very similar, but puts spaces between the strings it pastes. Also look into the `collapse=` parameter to `paste` and `paste0` if you're trying to paste together a vector of strings.